# Batch or script file to close program with a command then reopen it

Tags: bash, shell, minecraft

I am running a minecraft server off my machine and have found I need to shut down and restart the server once a day. I am trying to write a script file that will give the kill command to the server and after like 30 sec restart it.

Comment: You could use a `cron` entry to run `sudo init 6` on it which would reboot the server assuming you have `sudo` privileges. I don't know of a way though to introduce a pause of 30 seconds between shutting the server down and restarting it though.

Comment: Add the script your are using to launch minecraft-server and the command you are using to launch the script. What you need to do is get the `pid` of either **the script** (if it remains resident) or the `pid` of **minecraft-server** if the script has terminated after backgrounding the server -- so you can `kill -HUP pidofserver` either manually or from `cron`. You can also make this a bit more simple by writing the `pid` of the server to a file so it is available for restart (as with an init-script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script could be something like

```bash
minecraft-start & # change the cmd, keep the '&'
PID=$!; 
echo $PID > /tmp/minecraft.pid  # store PID, removed if physical server reboot
sleep 24h;  # wait 24 hours
kill $(cat /tmp/minecraft.pid)  # kill, what about active users and all?
```

As other have mentioned this could be in a cron task.

#### Explanation

`$!` contains the last [command process id](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement?highlight=%28PID%29#I_want_to_do_something_with_a_process_I_started_earlier) (*aka* PID)

Comment: Can I add in a command to post on the server of a server restart? Also where you have "Minecraft-start &" is Minecraft-start the cmd stuff?

Comment: @tucker19 of course you can add commands, but I'm not sure to understand your goal and it's probably better to ask a new question.

Comment: @tucker19 the `&` is important, the `minecraft-start` should be replaced by your command to start your minecraft server, it was just a placeholder.

Comment: I want a command to post onto the server for anyone on it that says "Server restarting, be back soon", also the actual command for the server would look like what?